# Compare histograms of specific areas of two images? OpenCV

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, histogram, image-comparison

Basically, I want to be able to compare two histograms, but not of whole images just specific areas. I have image A and have a specific rectangular region on it that I want to compare to another image B. Is there a way to get the histogram of a definable rectangular region on an image? I have the x y position of the rectangular area, as well as it's width and height, and want to get its histogram. I'm using opencv with python.

Sorry if that isn't very clear :(

(I'm setting up a program that takes a picture of a circuit board, and checks each solder pad for consistency with an image of a perfect board. If one pad is off, the program raises a flag saying that specific pad is off by x percent, not the whole board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following is in C++ but I think it is not hard to find the equivalent functions for python.

You can find the histogram of an image using [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html) tutorial. So for example for the lena image we get:

[image: lenahist]

In your case, since you have the rectangle coordinates, you can just extract the ROI of the image:

```
// C++ code
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("lena.png", 0);
cv::Rect roiRect = cv::Rect(150, 150, 250, 250);
cv::Mat imageRoi = image(roiRect);
```

and then find the histogram of just the ROI with the same way as above:

[image: lenaroihist]

Is this what you wanted (in theory at least) or I misunderstood?

Comment: That is pretty much what I was looking for. I didn't know about the ROI. Thank you very much! I am sure I'll run into more problems once I get deeper into my code, but this will help me tremendously. Thanks!