# OpenCV: How to match a template for a specfic region of a large image using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have template of size *100*100* px and image of 800*800. I don't want to search every possible region of size  *100*100* in that image. Instead I want to check whether my template exist in specific regions or not, to make it time efficient.
Let us consider *800*800* image in form of 2d grid of *8*8*. I just want to check it in these 64 regions *(8*8)* not *(701*701)* regions.
Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: The Sikuli library by MIT makes this easy. It can plug into python. Is that an option for you?

Comment: May be you can make your stride value variable where if the matching score is high then you will decrease the stride value otherwise you will increase it(upto a max threshold). This will surely compare more than 64 regions but it's a point to start.

Comment: Use setRoi(64 times) and absDiff(or similar methods) to find if template matches with one of the 8x8 grid objects.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow actually i am working on a project for that i have to do my task only on cv2 , but i still keep that one in my list for my further projects.

Comment: @Optimus1072  as i am a beginner so I don't know much about how to achieve what you are suggesting, may be a link will work.

Comment: Thanks @saurabheights I will try that one,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare histograms of specific areas of two images? OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750889/compare-histograms-of-specific-areas-of-two-images-opencv)